# Show that multiplication operator in $L^{\infty}$ is self adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to show that the following operator is self adjoint.

$$T:L^\infty[0,1]\rightarrow L^\infty[0,1]$$ such that $$(Tx)(t)=tx(t)$$

I am stuck mainly because I can't seem to find how the inner product is defined in $L^\infty$. I know that in $L^2$ we have that $$\langle Tx,y\rangle = \int_0^1 (Tx\bar{y})^2$$

Is there any equivalence to this for $L^\infty$?

Comment: That problem has no solution, since the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is not induced by an inner product.

Comment: Oh I see. Ok, thank you for the help on that. I am really trying to find that the spectrum = the point spectrum = $[0,1]$. I showed that the point spectrum is $[0,1]$  and I showed that all $|\lambda|\leq ||T||=1$ but I am stuck on how to show that there are no other spectral values. I was thinking that if I could show it was self adjoint then the spectral values are all real. But maybe it is enough since the space is $L^\infty[0,1]$...

Comment: Just try to explicitly write down an inverse of $T-\lambda$ if $\lambda\not\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I see what you mean. They are bounded and exist with no problem. So they are in the resolvent set I suppose :) My only uncertainty is how to show that they aren't in the residual spectrum.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The norm doesn't need to come from an inner product to be able to talk about adjoints, self-adjoint, etc. The real problem is that $L^\infty$ is not its own dual. If you take a [self-dual Banach space](https://mathoverflow.net/a/91360), you can perfectly consider operators in them that are self-adjoint.

Comment: Is this operator compact?

Comment: It makes no sense to say that this $T$ is self-adjoint. Because if $T:X\to YY$ then $T^*:Y^*\to X^*$, so here $T=T*$ is simply impossible; $T$ and $T^*$ are defined on different spaces. An operator from $L^2$ to itself can be self-adjoint, because $(L^2)^*=L^2$. (Regarding "I found it here:". No, the $T$ in that other post is a _different_ operator. Because it's defined on $L^2$, while the current one is defined on $L^\infty$.)